# Xdocument.load( ) does not refreshes with xml file update

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to build a small desktop scoreboard which can get and show live matches score in C#. Now when I call Xdocument.load(url) method on button click, it loads latest scores for the first time only, then keep showing the same score even though Xdocument.load() is defined to run on button click(as well as when Form loads,but I don't think that will make a difference).
Now what I have found on google and stackoverflow is something like to see when file is updated,and related stuff. But all those are for local xml files. How do I solve my problem?

```
     public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // WebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Revalidate);   
        feed = XDocument.Load(url);


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        feed = XDocument.Load(url + "?_=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
         feed=XDocument.Load(url);
       // var nofmlive = feed.Root.Element("match").Attribute("srs");
        var output = GetItems();
        foreach (var v in output) {
       //rest of the code,,just to get and show data of all matches which are currently live
```

Comment: Your question missing 5-7 lines of sample code. Also what is wrong with "are for local xml files"? What is location of your XML? Do you use cache busting for http(s) locations?

Comment: feed=XDocument.Load(@"http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml");  I don't see any relevant code in my small app. Its only like 30 lines of code,getting and showing attributes from this xml file.

Comment: That line would make question much more concrete. Also Darin (+1) figured out your code anyway (but sometimes people with telepathic abilities are sleeping :) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe `XDocument` is caching the data. Try busting the cache by appending a Guid query string parameter parameter:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(url + "?_=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

Adjust the `?` with `&` if you already have query string parameters in the url.

You might also try changing the cache policy but the drawback of this approach is that it is global to all HTTP requests:

```
WebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.Revalidate);
var doc = XDocument.Load(url);
```

Alternatively you may try loading the XML with a WebClient and then feeding it to the XDocument:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string xml = client.DownloadString("http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml?_=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
}
```

Comment: none of the two solutions is working for me. I defined a variable url and equated it to the url string and then wrote your first line of code as my first line of code on_button_click. Second solution didn't worked either. I tried running my app as admin,no use. What the hell m I doing??

Comment: Did you ensure that the XML file is actually updated on the remote server? You could use Fiddler to see the exact Request/Response being sent and debug the problem further.

Comment: I don't know if you are asking about meta-data of file itself(like modification date and so) but ya, the contents are updated every few seconds. I am watching match live, and also when I shut down my app and restart it real quickly, the update is shown.

Comment: Actually I was talking about the contents. When you are sending an HTTP request you are sending this request to an url, you don't actually know whether there's a file or not behind it. Probably there isn't in your case and there's a server side handler which generates the XML dynamically. By the way when I tried the url you have mentioned (http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml) it doesn't actually get updated that quickly. I tried it in the browser. I guess the problem you are encountering is not related to .NET code at all.

Comment: If you have just tried it(of course), there was a slight break in the match. Try it right now,the match is resumed. Once it starts getting updated, it keeps going on for all 6 balls in real quick time(like in 4 minutes or so,all 6 balls are covered)

Comment: Tried it just now - same thing. It doesn't get updated quite often. And by the way I've tested it with the XDocument and it worked as expected - it got updated. I am afraid I don't know how to help you any further.

Comment: Any suggestions on what alternative I can take? I searched for a long time to get this url-it the only one that gives complete score.

Comment: You may try using a WebClient.DownloadString() to download the XML and then feed it to the XDocument. I've updated my answer to illustrate an example.

Comment: You mean your code is working good? I am on Windows 8. Maybe I should test it on Win 7? I'll try to dig more to see what can be done. Anyways thanks.

Comment: I've tested the code on Windows 8 x64 bit and it is working fine. It's just that I had to wait a long time before the XML feed actually got updated because as I mentioned earlier it doesn't get updated very often.

Comment: Ya it worked. Thanks. I left a small bug somewhere else. Thankew! :-)